# Remove website URL from zRSS Feed

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, rss

I would like to remove the website URL that the RSS feed is originating from.

In the following example:  http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zrssfeed/example.html

I would like to remove **Reuters: Oddly Enough** from the feed.  I looked in the .js file under // Function to create HTML result...but not sure which line of code to comment out to remove this.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, dirty way:

Add this to your CSS:

`.rssHeader {
display: none;
}`

Or use [JSBeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) to format your Javascript code, so it's easier to find the line to uncomment.

Also make sure you have the right to leave out the source.

Comment: it worked beautifully!  Thank you so much for your quick response!!

Answer (score 0):

zRSSFeed has an option to remove the header link from the feed.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test').rssfeed('http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/oddlyEnoughNews',{
        header: false
    });
});
```